# Passing a value from html template to views.py in Django

Tags: python, django, geodjango

can you please help me with the issue I'm experiencing?
Basically, I followed a tutorial online to create a location-based application that displays the shops around the user's location. However, the longitude and latitude for the user are hard-coded in views.py.

```
views.py 

from django.http import request, HttpResponse
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance
from .models import Shop


longitude = 10.113
latitude = -2.231
user_location = Point(longitude, latitude, srid=4326)


class Home(generic.ListView):
    model = Shop
    context_object_name = 'shops'
    queryset = Shop.objects.annotate(distance=Distance('location',
    user_location)
    ).order_by('distance')[0:15]
    template_name = 'shops/index.html'
```

I added the Leaflet integration with my template so now I can I have access to the latitude and longitude variables for the user which I need to pass back to my views.py and update them there. Is that possible in general and what you be the solution for this?
Thank you a lot for the help

```
index.html

map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});

function onLocationFound(e)
 {
   var radius = e.accuracy;
   var lat = e.latlng.lat;
   var lon = e.latlng.lng;
   L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
           .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point"+  +lat+lon).openPopup();
            L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
 }
```

Comment: You would need to use Ajax for this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I came up with a solution in AJAX however I am still struggling to get this working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting django and the view alone to read the html content after it's been rendered / sent to the client without doing a network request is not possible.

You'd have to communicate back to the view using the network, so you could either have some JS send a request to your view or look into django websockets and channels.

https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

You could also use ajax or as previously mentioned in this answer use the request module and do e.g. a POST request.